# How do I change properties on the Navigation Bar in a WPF Frame?

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a page based WPF application, and I want to change the size of the navigation bar in the frame.  I set NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" in order to see the navigation bar, now how do I change properties on the navigation bar like it's size?

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: What navigation bar are you talking about? WPF doesn't have a built in one.

Comment: Yes it does, on the Frame object if you set  the property NavigationUIVisibility="Visible", you get a navigation bar.  For example,
http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2007/11/11/building-wpf-applications-with-the-page-navigation-framework-it-s-just-like-asp-net-but-with-state.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Navigation Bar is hard to change. I recommend you to create you own.
Create you own buttons and then use

```
myFrame.NavigationService.GoBack()
myFrame.NavigationService.GoForward()
```

Example:

```
Private Sub PreviousPageCommand_Executed(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    MainFrame.NavigationService.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub PreviousPageCommand_CanExecute(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
    If Not MainFrame Is Nothing Then
        e.CanExecute = MainFrame.NavigationService.CanGoBack
    Else
        e.CanExecute = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NextPageCommand_Executed(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    MainFrame.NavigationService.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub NextPageCommand_CanExecute(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                    ByVal e As CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
    If Not MainFrame Is Nothing Then
        e.CanExecute = MainFrame.NavigationService.CanGoForward
    Else
        e.CanExecute = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I wound up doing anyway...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to manipulate the default style menu

[Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms771597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is a sample project linked above that you can see not only the Nav menu but also other controls.

You basically create a style resource which replaces the default. The example they give you is a great start. Then you can tweak the resource to get the look you are after.